# Optimization as theorem proving?

Tags: logic, optimization, computer-science

There is sometimes need to find optimal rules, optimal policies, e.g. optimal Markov policy in symbolic form. E.g.see [article about symbolic planning and hierarchical reinforcement learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07779.pdf). My question is: are there ideas about symbolic optimization or planning as theorem proving, .I.e. formulate the optimization task as some theorem in some logic/logic theory and then see the proof of this theorem as solution? Or maybe there are other ways how to logically formulate the search for some optimal rule set, some optimal policy rules, some optimal grammar as some logical task and solve it using available theorem provers or SAT solvers?

Comment: Is this the article you mean? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07779.pdf

Comment: Exactly, I had no chance to link it.

Comment: Constraint logic programming with optimization is one way to explore..

Comment: There always is genetic programming methods and fitness function, but maybe there is some kind of symbolic gradient? I have heard that adjunction in category theory is some recipe of optimization, but no further idea.

Comment: Added the link to the post